# Issue with $row['{$variable}']

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create a several page survey that is saved each time they progress to the next page. If they then leave and go back to the start, all the information is auto-filled in the fields.

First I select all the previously saved data:

```
$survey = $_GET['survey'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id='{$survey}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Then later on I use a loop to fetch all the questions on a page with information auto-filled if it's present in the $row array.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id in (1,2,3)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($items = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($items['type'] == "text"){ 
        $value = $items['name']; ?>
        <p><?php echo $items['question']; ?> <input type="text" id="<?php echo $items['name']; ?>" name="<?php echo $items['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['{$value}']; ?>" /></p>
        <?php }
    }
```

An example of the tables:

QUESTIONS

id,type,name,question

1,text,first_name,What is your first name?

2,text,last_name, What is your last name?

DATA

id,first_name,last_name

1,John,Doe

Everything seems to be working except for:

```
value="<?php echo $row['{$value}']; ?>"
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the problem. Fortunately in this case it just so happens to be identifiable to experts. In which part of the PHP manual did you see to write anything like `$row['{$value}']`?

Comment: To Non-Stop Time Travel:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Array do's and don'ts
Why is $foo[bar] wrong?

Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts.

Comment: To Marc B ... How would the server be 'pwn3d' with no submit and no Update/Insert? Clearly I haven't posted the actual code. - And re: previous comment...just continued reading to "Do not quote keys which are constants or variables, as this will prevent PHP from interpreting them." :(

Comment: @JoeKimberger `"SELECT * FROM data WHERE id='{$survey}'"` where `$survey`is directly read from $_GET. What if `$survey="1'; DROP TABLES;"; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the quotes, they make it a string literal instead of a variable.   (brackets probably aren't necessary either):

```
value="<?php echo $row[$value]; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be, no need for `'`

```
value="<?php echo $row[$value]; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is for one, you're using single quotes which do not execute PHP variables or functions but takes the text as-is. If you use double quotes, the {$var} would be taken as the variable. However, in this case, you do not need the quotes at all.

use:

```
<?php echo $row[$value]; ?>
```